# Unable to display custom error page in nginx

Tags: nginx

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to display a custom maintenance page on every IP address (That request my site) except my own IP address.

**What Is the problem ?**

nginx doesn't display my custom maintenance page instead it displays a default `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error message.

**My nginx code:**

```
...   
location / {          
    if (-f /path/to/maintenance.html){  
        return 501;
    }
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}         
error_page 501 = @ip_proxy;      
location @ip_proxy {        
    if ($remote_addr != <my_ip>){
        return 503;         
    }
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}    
error_page 503 /maintenance.html;
location = /maintenance.html {
    root /path/to/parent/directory/of/maintenance.html;
}
location @proxy_to_app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
...
```

Whenever I am done with maintenance of my site I just rename the `maintenance.html` to something else to bring back my site. Which breaks the If condition in first `location`.

Comment: In general the usage of if statement in Nginx is not recommended. [Check (If) File Exists is bad](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists). Moreover you can turn debug level on to see what is the exact error you get. [Nginx  debugging log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html)

Comment: @Gal S Thanks for your reply. I set the debug level on and saw some errors. So I fixed them but now I am still not able to display the maintenance page. Please help.

Comment: @Gal S Okay How can you use `try_files` to check for an existence of a file and then instead of serving it goto a location. ?

Comment: @Ahishtam Sorry for late response, I see you managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after lot of testing I came to a solution :) and here its:

```
location / {                
    try_files /does_not_exist @ip_proxy;
}        
location @ip_proxy {        
    if ($remote_addr != <my_ip>){
        return 503;         
    }
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}        
error_page 503 = @maintenance;    
location @maintenance {                        
    root /path/to/error_page;
    try_files /maintenance.html @proxy_to_app; 
}
```

I tried to move the `@ip_proxy` code in `location /` but that was displaying maintenance page on all IP address included mine.